# .asc viewer using Kivy

Tags: python, 3d, kivy

I want to develop a 3D file viewer in kivy and python that reads and displays .asc mesh files of the format:

```
x1,y1,z1
x2,y2,z2
........
xi,yi,zi
```

What I have thought so far is to use a method similar to `beginShape()` of Processing so as to begin drawing a 3D shape then use a for-loop to append each point respectively.

I have also found that kivy example which parses `.obj` files and then displays them. Do you have any ideas on how can I make a similar ascparser and try to display my files?

Any help is greatly appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I have also found that kivy example which parses .obj files and then displays them. Do you have any ideas on how can I make a similar ascparser and try to display my files?

Your best strategy at the moment is probably to read the objparser and try to understand what it is doing. The important thing is building a list of points and normals, which are passed to opengl via a Mesh with a custom vertex_format and custom shaders. In principle it wouldn't be very hard to do the same thing for your own filetype just by comparison with the .obj code, though you will need some understanding of what's going on (you can read about opengl and read the kivy source, if you haven't already) to make significant changes.

This is really an advanced topic right now, Kivy has very few pre-built wrappers to 3d opengl rendering. The backend is fully capable (so the 3d rendering example isn't that complex, for instance), but you probably do need some understanding of what's going on to accomplish things like your own task.

There are also a few other examples of 3d rendering in Kivy, which you might find helpful. nskrypnik has [several repositories](https://github.com/nskrypnik?tab=repositories) doing just this (see kivy-trackball, kivy-3dpicking, kivy-rotation3d), and seems to have begun implementing a proper 3d api in the kivy3 repo, though this is *not* complete and I suggest it as something you can learn about by reading, not something that can necessarily do what you want right now. The other nice example I've seen is a [3d inspector POC](https://gist.github.com/tito/5411449) by tito, though it's just a proof of concept and not a polished product.